# Toggle some elements to show in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, show-hide, slidetoggle

I'd like to have the elements which are toggled to hide instead (on load) and then toggle them to display.

I have a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q7kPE/) going which shows the effects, but the other way around when all elements are visible and then toggled so that all but two are hidden. If possible all `depth-1` (top level) comments should display two replies on pageload. The last comment - `comment-687` - should then be visible together with its parent `comment-682`, but I haven't worked out how to have two comments as default in all scenarios.

Here is html

```
 <ol class="commentlist">
    <li class="comment byuser comment-author-admin even thread-even depth-1" id="li-comment-677">
        <div id="comment-677" class="grandparent">
            <div class="comment-inner">comment-677
            </div>
            <ul class="children">
                <li class="comment byuser comment-author-admin odd alt depth-2" id="li-comment-678">
                    <div id="comment-678" class="parent">
                        <div class="comment-inner">comment-678</div>
                        <ul class="children">
                            <li class="comment byuser comment-author-admin even depth-3" id="li-comment-680">
                                <div id="comment-680">
                                    <div class="comment-inner">comment-680</div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li class="comment byuser comment-author-admin odd alt depth-3" id="li-comment-686">
                                <div id="comment-686">
                                    <div class="comment-inner">comment-686</div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li class="comment byuser comment-author-admin even depth-3" id="li-comment-688">
                                <div id="comment-688">
                                    <div class="comment-inner">comment-688</div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li class="comment byuser comment-author-admin odd alt depth-3" id="li-comment-689">
                                <div id="comment-689">
                                    <div class="comment-inner">comment-689</div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="comment byuser comment-author-admin even depth-2" id="li-comment-698">
                    <div id="comment-698" class="parent">
                        <div class="comment-inner">comment-698</div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="comment byuser comment-author-admin odd alt thread-odd thread-alt depth-1" id="li-comment-679">
        <div id="comment-679" class="grandparent">
            <div class="comment-inner">comment-679</div>
            <ul class="children">
                <li class="comment byuser comment-author-admin even depth-2" id="li-comment-682">
                    <div id="comment-682" class="parent">
                        <div class="comment-inner">comment-682</div>
                        <ul class="children">
                            <li class="comment byuser comment-author-admin odd alt depth-3" id="li-comment-690">
                                <div id="comment-690">
                                    <div class="comment-inner">comment-690</div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="comment byuser comment-author-admin even depth-2" id="li-comment-691">
                    <div id="comment-691" class="parent">
                        <div class="comment-inner">comment-691</div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="comment byuser comment-author-admin odd alt depth-2" id="li-comment-692">
                    <div id="comment-692" class="parent">
                        <div class="comment-inner">comment-692</div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>

    <li class="comment byuser comment-author-admin even thread-even depth-1" id="li-comment-681">
        <div id="comment-681" class="grandparent">
            <div class="comment-inner">comment-681</div>
            <ul class="children">
                <li class="comment byuser comment-author-admin odd alt depth-2" id="li-comment-683">
                    <div id="comment-683" class="parent">
                        <div class="comment-inner">comment-682</div>
                        <ul class="children">
                            <li class="comment byuser comment-author-admin even depth-3" id="li-comment-687">
                                <div id="comment-687">
                                    <div class="comment-inner">comment-687</div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
</ol>
```

Javascript:

```
$('ol').find('> li > div > ul')
.before('<div class="toggle">Show all replies</div>');

$('.commentlist').find('div.toggle').click(function () {
    $(this).next('ul').find('.depth-2:gt(1)').slideToggle(); 
    $(this).next('ul').find('.depth-3').slideToggle();
});
```

Comment: @Jay Blanchard  Thanks. More correct is class `depth-1` - it is the top-level comment (grandparent). I updated my question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It takes a little slicing and dicing, but this should work for you - http://jsfiddle.net/jayblanchard/Q7kPE/1/

```
$('ol').find('> li > div > ul')
    .before('<div class="toggle">Show all replies</div>');

/* added this function to hide all but 2 of the d3's where appropriate */
$('.depth-1').each(function() {
    var d3Length = $(this).find('.depth-3').length;
    if(d3Length > 1) { // only want this to affect those with 2 or more d3's
        var $d3 = $(this).find('.depth-3');
        $d3.hide().slice(0, 2).show(); // hide all and then show the first two
    }
});

$('.commentlist').find('div.toggle').click(function () {
    $(this).next('ul').find('.depth-2:gt(1)').slideToggle();
    /* re-factored the code here to take into account the number of d3's */
    var d3Length = $(this).next('ul').find('.depth-3').length; 
    if(d3Length > 1) { // affect only those with 2 or more d3's       
        $(this).next('ul').find('.depth-3:gt(1)').slideToggle(); // slide toggle all of the remaining d3's
    } else {
        $(this).next('ul').find('.depth-3').slideToggle();
    }
});
```

Comment: @ Jay Blanchard Thank you very much! Your answer is extremely helpful to me. I updated your fiddle and I have nearly got it right now. There is still a minor issue with getting two replies to show as default in all cases which I have illlustrated [link]http://jsfiddle.net/cAdu3/ - see 3 and 5 in the list.

Comment: I had that working in the original fiddle, along with your other requirement for the list. You may have to setup a case for those, just as I did before.

Comment: @ Jay Blanchard Sorry, this is the correct fiddle: [link]http://jsfiddle.net/cAdu3/1/

Comment: You have some errors you're setting variables when you do this `if(d2Length = 1)`. This always evaluates to 'true'.

Comment: @ Jay Blanchard Yes, I noticed that, the code surely has more errors, but it is working for the most part. I'll have to do some more learning, I am quite a beginner when it comes to javascript.